# How to handle square brackets in correlation handle of Receive activity in windows workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I have a windows workflow that has a Receive activity that correlates on two string variables, x and y, where it's possible that y may be enclosed in square brackets, e.g. "[some data]".  When y is enclosed in square brackets, I notice two interesting things:

1. When the workflow is serialized, the reference to y becomes "%[some data]".  That is, a percent is inserted before the square bracket.
2. I am unable to meet the correlation condition.  I have tried "[some data]", "%[some data]", "`[some data`] - but nothing seems to work.

Is there some advice on both how to handle the situation where a correlation variable may contain square brackets?  Is there anything I can do with my existing workflows so that 
they can meet the correlation condition?

**Edit**

My specific issue, I realize, is with the correlation.  I am creating my workflow service programmatically and the Receive activity looks something like:

```
var receiveRequest = new Receive
{
    DisplayName = "Receive", 
    OperationName = "DoIt", 
    CanCreateInstance = true, 
    ServiceContractName = "MyService", 
    SerializerOption = SerializerOption.DataContractSerializer, 
    Content = receiveParameters, 
    CorrelatesOn = new MessageQuerySet 
    {
        { "x", new XPathMessageQuery("sm:body()/foo:DoIt/foo:x", myNamespaceManager) }, 
        { "y", new XPathMessageQuery("sm:body()/foo:DoIt/foo:y", myNamespaceManager) }, 
    }, 
    CorrelatesWith = actionCorrelationHandle, 
    CorrelationInitializers = 
    {
        new RequestReplyCorrelationInitializer 
        {
            CorrelationHandle = requestReplyHandleVariable
            }
        }
    };
```

The above works fine, unless y contains right square bracket "]".

Thanks,
Eric